# Is it possible to ToString() an expression property when using `Expression.Equal`?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm doing this:

```
var selectorParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "c");
var selector = GetPropertyOrField<T>(selectorParameter, "CatId");
var comparisonValue = Expression.Constant("1");

var result = Expression.Equal(selector, comparisonValue);
```

This throws an error saying it cannot compare `int32` and `string`

The easiest fix for this will be to do a `ToString()` on the property before the comparison. However I can't figure out how to do this. My guess is that I build another expression, possibly to do a method call to ToString(), but I am not sure how to feed that back in.

Comment: `Expression.Equal(selector.ToString(), comparisonValue)`?

Comment: Nice try but it takes an `Expression` as a parameter, not a string. So I'd have to build the `ToString()` into the `Expression`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make the comparison value an `int`?

Comment: @NibblyPig Ah ok no go then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Expression.Call` in order to create a method call expression:

```
// Expression for: c.CatId.ToString()
var stringExpr =
    Expression.Call(selector, selector.Type.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[]{}));

// Expression for: c.CatId.ToString() == "1"
var result = Expression.Equal(stringExpr, comparisonValue);
```

Comment: Version before edit was better, because nothing prevents me to declare method `ToString` that takes parameters (and many classes do so), in which case this will throw AmbiguousMatchException.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the type as it's generic and could be different types. although since ToString() is on Object, perhaps it'd work with that.

Comment: Well you can just do `typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString")` I think, since it's indeed method of object after all.

Comment: Of which `object`? We must use the type of the selector expression, i.e. the static type of the expression `c.CatId`, which can vary according to NibblyPig.

Comment: Of type `object` (`System.Object`). It will also work in this case, however you are right that it's more reasonable to use `selector.Type` instead of `typeof(object)`, just because it's more clear.

Comment: Does it work with `typeof(object)` even when the method is overridden?

Comment: Yes. To be sure you can create some object, override `ToString` and then do `typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString").Invoke(new YourObject(), new object[0]);`. Works correctly when used in expression too.

Comment: I'm sure this code works great, seems I have hit another problem in that I am using entity framework and I get `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."` :-( But I guess that's a problem for another day.

Comment: @NibblyPig and which version of Entity Framework you are using? Because versions 6.1+ should support ToString just fine.

Comment: Then probably a simple cast expression should work: `var stringExpr = Expression.Convert(selector, typeof(string));`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it said that EF can't convert to a string. I've bypassed the problem for now but I have a similar question that I will ask in a new question